# Mount systemd-homed user directory in another machine

Tags: linux, encryption, mount, systemd

A computer I have uses systemd-homed for users, it has a single user and a single LUKS-encrypted home directory. That computer has an issue and won't boot anymore, but the disk is still working. However, I could not find how do I mount this home directory to another computer, with another user logged in.

So, how do I mount a LUKS-encrypted home directory created with systemd-homed in another machine, without booting to its disk, mounting the partitions instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a definitive [answer from GaKu999 at Arch Linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=258152). To mount a systemd-homed home directory in another machine without booting to that disk, run the following commands:

1. First, use `losetup` to setup a loopback device to the home directory file:

`$ sudo losetup -f -P <username>.home`

2. Then, use `cryptsetup` to open the encrypted LUKS volume. It will be mapped to `/dev/loopXpY`, where X is the loopback device index and Y is the partition index (e.g. `/dev/loop0p1`). Here, it will ask for the directory password (it is the user password for that device):

`$ sudo cryptsetup open /dev/loopXpY <alias>`

3. At last, mount it from `/dev/mapper/<alias>`, using `<alias>` as specified in the previous step:

`$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/<alias> /path/to/mountpoint`

Now, the encrypted home directory will be accessible from `/path/to/mountpoint`!

Answer (score 0):

Ideal, and certainly the fastest/easiest would be to boot the machine with a linux LiveCD/LiveUSB
You will be able to mount the disc and use all the necessary verification tools

Comment: It will not boot due to a motherboard issue, but the computer is too old to be worth the repair.